# Implement Parallel.Foreach inside a while loop

Tags: c#, foreach, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have scenario where I need to run a Parallel.Foreach within a while loop. I need to understand the impact of this implementation in terms of how the processing will take place. I will have an implementation something like this

```
 ConcurrentQueue<MyTable> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<MyTable>();
```

Here, I have initially added lot of items in queue but while execution also, more items can be added in the queue.

```
while(true)
{
    Parallel.Foreach(queue, (myTable) => {some processing});
    Sleep(sometime);
}
```

Each time one item will be de-queued and new thread will be spawned to work with it, in the meanwhile new items will be added for that I need to keep an infinite while loop.

Now, I need to understand that as concurrent queue is thread safe, I think each item will be processed one time only in spite of while above foreach but I am not sure about is that there will be multiple threads of foreach itself that will be spawning child threads or single copy of foreach will be running within while loop. I do not know how foreach itself is implemented.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but `Parallel.Foreach()` will wait until it's tasks are complete before continuing on, as if it were any simple statement.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You don't need an infinite loop to poll for new items if you know when new items are added.

Comment: How are you removing processed items from the queue?

Comment: @kingjah I need infinite loop, because parallel.foreach will exit, if no items are added and all running tasks are completed.

Comment: @svick I am removing items within "some processing" logic.

Comment: @Jonesy From my POC for above command, I seeing the behavior I expected. Suppose initially I have 10 items in queue and max degree of parallelism is 5 then it will start 5 threads. Here it will constantly loop around in while loop but total number of threads spawned by foreach remains equal to number of items in the queue.
Similarly, even on adding new items ad-hoc, it spawns parallel number of threads equal to max degree of parallelism.

Comment: @Shoe My question was that whether .Net Framework treats parallel.foreach same as any other code statement in while loop. Or during second iteration it starts new thread for parallel.foreach itself. So, if it started new thread during second iteration for parallel.foreach then two parallel.foreach's will be spawning child threads and overall screwing up with degree of parallelism.

Comment: It doesn't create new threads it creates new tasks. Those tasks can be completed by one thread or many threads. If your action operates on some shared resource then yes, you can have concurrency problems. So you need to be sure those resources are atomic. Note that `Parallel.Foreach` is less useful when each task has to wait for some resource to unlock because the whole point is to run things in parallel, not serially.

Answer (score 4):

> I have scenario where I need to run a Parallel.Foreach within a while loop.

I don't think you do. You want to process new items as they come in in parallel, but I think this is not the best way to do that.

I think the best way is to use [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684) from TPL Dataflow. It won't waste CPU or threads when there are no items to process and if you set its `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, it will process items in parallel:

```
ActionBlock<MyTable> actionBlock = new ActionBlock<MyTable>(
    myTable => /* some processing */,
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded
    });


...

actionBlock.Post(someTable);
```

If you don't want to or can't (it's .Net 4.5 only) use TPL Dataflow, another option would be use a single `Parallel.Foreach()` (no `while`) together with [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) and [`GetConsumingPartitioner()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx) (**not** `GetConsumingEnumerable()`!).

Using this, the `Parallel.Foreach()` threads will be blocked when there are no items to process, but there also won't be any delays in processing (like the ones caused by your `Sleep()`):

```
BlockingCollection<MyTable> queue = new BlockingCollection<MyTable>();

...

Parallel.ForEach(
    queue.GetConsumingPartitioner(), myTable => /* some processing */);

...

queue.Add(someTable);
```

---

> I think each item will be processed one time only in spite of while above foreach but I am not sure

That's one reason why you should use one of the options above, since they mean you don't need to know much about the details of how they work, they just work.

Comment: I have >100 biometric n/w devices, I need to read/write data from/to them. what is your advise regarding the above case. which methods is more efficient for my case. I was using  P.For() inside while() BUt after I read your post, I came to know Im wrong. so please advise.